# Discord.js a function called in a switch instruction doesnt' work very well

Tags: function, discord.js

This is the part of my code that doesn't work fine:

```js
var Prefix = '?';


Client.on("message",message=>{
    if(message.author!=Client.user)
    {
        FindCommands(message);
        console.log("message traité avec succès");
    }
});


function FindCommands(message){
    var content = message.content;
    var channel = message.channel;
    switch(content.toLowerCase()){
        case "ping":
        case Prefix+"ping":
            channel.send("pong");
            break;
        case Prefix+"help":
            message.channel.send(commandsMessage.content.slice(9));
            break;
        case Prefix+"membre":
        case Prefix+"member":
            becameMember(message);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return;
}


function becameMember(theMessage){
    var n;
    n=AddRole(theMessage.member,'756058147063595069');
    console.log(n);
    return;
}


function AddRole(theGuildMember,theRoleId,theMessage){
    if(theGuildMember.roles.cache.find(aRole=> aRole.id === theRoleId)==null &&theGuildMember.guild.id=='576710367041028109')
    {
        theGuildMember.roles.add(theRoleId).then(()=>{
            console.log("role attribué avec succès");
            theMessage.channel.send("**"+theMessage.author.username+"** est devenu un membre");
        }).catch(nbr=>{
            console.log("impossible d'ajouter le role");
            return 0;
        });
    }else return 0;
}
```

When i send "?member" or "?membre" on discord in the correct guild The bot add to my roles the role "member" but the bot don't answer to me: *"**"+theMessage.author.username+"*** est devenu un membre"

I'm french i hope you'll understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass `theMessage` into your `AddRole` function, which expects 3 arguments. So, it is undefined.

```js
function becameMember(theMessage) {
    var n;
    // Yours: n=AddRole(theMessage.member,'756058147063595069');
    n=AddRole(theMessage.member,'756058147063595069', theMessage);
    console.log(n);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just spend one hour on this error!

Comment: Awesome. Don't forget to mark it as answered @Brinax

Comment: How can I do that?